# Read line of numeric data into an array, then read next line into a variable. C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am pretty new to coding so I am sure this is a stupid question. For a class I need to code an algorithm that determines the least amount of change to make some amount of money in C++.

This code needs to read numbers from a txt file so that the first line is the coin types (aka 1 cent, 2 cents, 4 cents, etc.). The second line is the total number that I want sorted into change. Then third line is a new set of coin types and the fourth line is a new total. The general pattern continues.

The txt file looks like -

```
1 2 5
10
1 3 7 12
29
1 2 4 8
15
1 7 11
14
```

I easily created the change algorithm myself, I am having problems getting the first line to be read into an array and then the next line to be read into a variable.

My code for the coinChange algorithm.

```
    int coinChange(int coins[], int total, int size)
    {
        //Set high minimum
        int min = 999999999;
        //For all of the coins, see if it equals the value of total
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (coins[i] == total) {
                //If so return 1
                return 1;
            }
        }
        //Loop through
        for (int j = 1; j <= total / 2; j++) {
            if ((coinChange(coins, j, size) + coinChange(coins, total - j, size)) < min) {
                min = coinChange(coins, j, size) + coinChange(coins, total - j, size);
            }
        }
        return min;
    }
```

I have tried using fgets and fscanf with no success so any advice would be very helpful.

Comment: You're using C++, so please, *use* C++. Don't use C-style arrays when `std::vector` or other containers are available. This will make your code simpler, less likely to have silly bugs, and opens up a whole world of tools that operate on Standard Library containers.

Answer (score 1):

If you use c++ as tadman commented already you can use something like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss("1 2 5\n10\n1 3 7 12\n29\n");
    std::string line;

    while(std::getline(ss, line))
    {
        std::stringstream lines(line);
        std::vector<int> values;
        std::string string_value;

        while(std::getline(lines, string_value, ' '))
            values.push_back(std::stoi(string_value));

        std::getline(ss, line);

        int value = std::stoi(line);

        std::cout << "got: ";
        for(const auto& v : values) std::cout << v << ", ";
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Try it here http://cpp.sh/33bmy .

Answer (score 0):

This reads a complete line and splits the coin types apart using a [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream). The total amount on the next line is extracted the usual way.

I changed your function signature to take a `std::vector` and an `int`. Most of your code should remain the same if you replace your use of `size` with `coins.size()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int coinChange(const std::vector<int> &coins, int total)
{
    // Set high minimum
    int min = 999999999;
    //
    // Your code here. Don't need a size parameter, use coins.size() instead
    //
    return min;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> coins;
    int total;

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, line) && std::cin >> total) {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        for (int coin; iss >> coin; ) {
            coins.push_back(coin);
        }

        coinChange(coins, total);

        coins.clear(); // reset vector before the next inputs
    }
}
```

Note: the use of [`std::ws`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws) inside the `std::getline` call is there to consume any leftover whitespace or newline from a previous input.